# parameter of a quantum group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

I am currently learning about quantum groups, and I got a question about how two different ways of thinking the $q$-parameter of quantum groups are related to each other. Here by a quantum group, I mean a $q$-analogue of a universal enveloping algebras of symmetrizable Kac-Moody algebra. Say that we work on the ground field $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a symmetrizable Kac-Moody algebra. I've seen two different ways of defining quantum groups:

1. we introduce a formal variable $q$, and then a quantum group is a $\mathbb{C}(q)$-algebra defined by quantum Weyl relations and quantum Serre relations of $\mathfrak{g}$ (for example, [1] and [2])
2. we choose $q\in\mathbb{C}$ which is different from $\pm 1$, and then a quantum group is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra defined by quantum Weyl relations and quantum Serre relations of $\mathfrak{g}$ (for example, [3])

It seems to me that the widespread knowledge is that, as long as $q$ is not a root of unity, the representation theory of the quantum group in the second definition is 'pretty much the same' to that of the quantum group in the first definition regarding $q$ as a formal variable. I want to know the precise statement for that. Following [1], let $\mathcal{O}_{\text{int}}$ be the full subcategory of integrable representations whose weight space is finitely dominated. This is the category where the crystal base theory works.

> Q1. To which extent would they be the same? Would we get a categorical equivalence between those two versions of either the category of finite-dimensional representations or $\mathcal{O}_{\text{int}}$?

I would really appreciate if you could recommend me a reference where I could find the precise statement. Also, I would like to ask:

> Q2. Say that $\mathfrak{g}$ be semisimple. If the answer to Q1 is that there is a categorical equivalence between two versions of $\mathcal{O}_{\text{int}}$, then would it respect the braided tensor category structures?

[1] M. Kashiwara, On crystal bases of the
Q
-analogue of universal enveloping algebras (1991)

[2] J. Hong, S.J. Kang, Introduction to Quantum Groups and Crystal Bases (2002)

[3] C. Kassel, Quantum Groups (1995)